# MemoryError When Resize Mnist data set images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am new on deep learning.I am trying to change mnist images from 28*28 into 224 * 224.

So I decided to use resize method. After importing MNIST dataset I try to resized it:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train_small = tf.image.resize(X_train, (224,224)).numpy()
```

But I got this error

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 11.2 GiB for an array with shape (60000, 224, 224, 1) and data type float32
```

My computer is old and I have just **16gig** ram. How can I resize Mnist data set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) and resize images on the fly, as batches pass:

```
import tensorflow as tf

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

resize = lambda x, y: (tf.image.resize(tf.expand_dims(x, -1), (224, 224)), y)

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).map(resize)

for image, label in train_ds.take(5):
    print(image.shape)
```

```
(224, 224, 1)
(224, 224, 1)
(224, 224, 1)
(224, 224, 1)
(224, 224, 1)
```

You can pass this dataset directly to `model.fit(train_ds)`

Comment: Thanks, But how can I normalize train_ds? Beacuse when I am trying to  train_ds/=255 I got error.@NicolasGervais

Comment: Just put `x/255` in `tf.expand_dims`

Comment: Should be `tf.float32` but you can use `next(iter(train_ds))` and inspect a batch of `(images, labels)`